# Make a Python member method that controls access from outside a class but not inside?

Tags: python

I'm mostly aware of Python's weird relationship with access modifiers, as they appear in C++ and friends. I am trying to create a getter or setter with *either* the following properties:

1. Is invoked by accesses from outside the class but not inside, C# property style
2. Is invoked by all accesses except those in the `__init__` method.

None of `__getattribute__`, `__getattr__`, `@property` provide these. Having 2 lets me work around 1, but 1 is preferable.

The Class I have represents a hierarchy with strict rules, the accessors should make sure that a given property is free to be changed when that data is not in the hierarchy, but is locked once it has been inserted and the rules on that data have already been checked.

I thought about creating a Factory class to enforce this, but then I'd just manifest the same problem in the Factory. Either the Factory needs to be the only way to insert objects in the hierarchy, a kind of exclusive access I don't think Python supports, or you could just change properties of the produced object before adding them, breaking the rules.

Wrt. 2, the fact that all the above forms of accessor are invoked even by accesses in the `__init__` method is Bad. Sure that's technically [uniform access](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overzealous), but as a result anything I do in that accessor must be correct for any partially initialized object. That is, the order of access in my init matters. Gross.

Comment: Are you willing to use static analysis to enforce these constraints (like you would in a compiled language), or does it need to be enforced at runtime?

Comment: It needs to be enforced at runtime, as the hierarchy may be built by reading a file.

Comment: Would a `@dataclass(frozen=True)` with validation in `__post_init__` do the trick?  That's what I typically do when I need to read in "dirty" data and make it "clean".

Answer (score 0):

You can't reliably do any kind of access control in Python. There is always a way around it, usually an easy and obvious one.

Here's a `__getattribute__` method I wrote that attempts to prevent private attributes from being accessed from outside the class. This is from a string subclass that tries to help programmers deal with "unsafe" data by throwing an error if you don't properly escape the string for some specific use (e.g. HTML, JavaScript...) using methods the class provides. So in theory the programmer is intentionally subjecting themselves to stricter discipline and would want to know if they accidentally did something to break this discipline. I'm not trying to really prevent accessing these attributes, then, but rather letting the programmer know if they've accidentally done that.

```
# require that all accesses to "private" attributes come from a method of the class they're attached to.
#
# the approach used is: from the stack frame of the caller, get the caller's code object.  using that code object's name,
# try to find a method of the same name on our class.  if this succeeds, make sure that method has same code object.
#
#  this can be easily circumvented... like everything in Python... but maybe it'll make you think twice.
if impl == "CPython":
    if __debug__:
        def __getattribute__(self, name):
            if name.startswith("_"):
                frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
                code = frame.f_code
                func = getattr(type(self), code.co_name, lambda: 0)
                if isinstance(func, property):
                    func = func.fget
                if getattr(func, "__code__", None) is not code:
                    raise AttributeError(f"private attribute {name} may not be accessed outside of {type(self).__name__} instance")
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
else:
    warn(f"{type(self).__name__}: private attributes are only enforced in CPython, not {impl}")
```

You could easily update this with other criteria, i.e. allow any class's `__init__` to access the "protected" attributes.

This isn't drop-in code, there are imports and other definitions to make it work... but the ease with which you can get around it is found in this line:

```
return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```

Which is all you'd have to do to bypass the "security."

Also note that it impacts performance enough that I included a check to make it run only in debug mode (without -O flag).

Comment: Preventing all undesired access is not so important to me as making deliberate circumvention look like what it is, as your example does. Programmers have a tendency to intuit a mode of operation that may be wrong, and I want the answer to their subconscious question "Would it tell me if this was incorrect usage?" to be "Yes".

Comment: Yeah, there are use cases for this sort of thing. I justified it because unescaped strings can be a security issue. OTOH it's counter to the Zen of Python ("we're all consenting adults here")